# Where is the laptop brightness script located?

Tags: shortcut-keys, scripts, laptop, brightness, backlight

Online I found the command:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

to set my screen brightness to the lowest possible value, currently I am grepping my entire disk for that path, looking for where the laptop hotkey script is so I can change the step size to 1 (so pressing my hotkeys would only change the brightness by 1 percent). I know some people might find this slow, but I am really critical of my night-time screen brightness, and the lower end of the range is much more noticeable thus my desire to have fine control over it.

Comment: sorry but I don't see any mention of the hotkey script location there

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the backlight brightness step size cannot be adjusted but is fixed in the device firmware.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the answer to my question (which would be convenient), but instead [coded up a Python GUI with a slider. I made two versions, one with wxPython and one with Tk.](https://gist.github.com/nmz787/ff7ae7b64d59070390ea)

Here's the tk version, which is shorter:

```
import os
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *

class BrightnessSlider(object):
    find_max_brightness_cmd = ['cat', '/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness']
    find_brightness_cmd = ['cat', '/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness']

    def __init__(self, master):
        min_brightness = 92
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(self.find_brightness_cmd,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p2 = subprocess.Popen(self.find_max_brightness_cmd,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        current_brightness, stderr = p1.communicate()
        max_brightness, stderr = p2.communicate()

        self.slider = Scale(master,
                  from_=int(min_brightness),
                  to=int(max_brightness),
                  orient=HORIZONTAL,
                  command=self.on_slide)
        self.slider.set(current_brightness)
        self.slider.pack()
        self.slider.focus_set()

    def on_slide(self, new_value):
        self.set_brightness(new_value)

    def set_brightness(self, new_val):
        with open('/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness', 'w') as f:
            f.write(new_val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    b = BrightnessSlider(master)
    mainloop()
```